# Parse String and Replace Letters Java

Tags: java, string, char

At input i have some string : "today snowing know " , here i have 3 words , so i must to parse them is such way : every character i must compare with all other characters , and to sum how many same characters these words have , like exemple for "o" letter will be 2 (from "today" and "snowing")  or "w" letter will be 2 (from "know" and "snowing"). After that i must to replace these characters with number(transformed in char format) of letters. The result should be "13111 133211 1332".

What i did ?

First i tape some words and

```
    public void inputStringsForThreads () {

       boolean flag;

            do {

    // will invite to input 
                stringToParse = Input.value();   

                try {

                flag = true;

    // in case that found nothing , space , number and other special character , throws an exception
                if (stringToParse.equals("") | stringToParse.startsWith(" ") | stringToParse.matches(".*[0-9].*") | stringToParse.matches(".*[~`!@#$%^&*()-+={};:',.<>?/'_].*"))

                    throw new MyStringException(stringToParse);

                else  analizeString(stringToParse);    
            }

            catch (MyStringException exception) {

                stringToParse = null;
                flag = false;
                exception.AnalizeException();  
            } 
          }
            while (!flag);
}
```

I eliminate spaces between words , and from those words make just one

```
   static void analizeString (String someString) {

// + sign treat many spaces as one
      String delimitator = " +";

// words is a String Array
      words = someString.split(delimitator);

// temp is a string , will contain a single word
      temp = someString.replaceAll("[^a-z^A-Z]","");


         System.out.println("=============== Words are : ===============");
      for (int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
          System.out.println((i+1)+")"+words[i]);
    }
```

So i try to compare for every word in part (every word is split in letters) with all letter from all words , But i don know how to count number of same letter and after replace letters with correct number of each letter??? Any ideas ?

```
// this will containt characters for every word in part 
         char[] motot  =   words[id].toCharArray();

// this will containt all characters from all words     
         char[] notot = temp.toCharArray();


   for (int i =0;i<words[i].length();i++)

               for (int j=0;j<temp.length ;j++)

               {
                   if (i == j) {

                       System.out.println("Same word");

                   }

                   else   if (motot[i] == notot[j] ) {

                       System.out.println("Found equal :"+lol[i]+" "+lol1[j]);

                   }}
```

Comment: Try a `HashMap<Character,Integer>`.

Comment: What about upper / lower case letters (are they considered the same character for counting purposes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For counting you might want to use a `Map<Character, Integer> counter` like `java.util.HashMap`. If getting a Value(Integer) using a specific key (Character) from counter is 'not null', then your value++ (leverage autoboxing). Otherwise put a new entry (char, 1) in the counter.

Replacing the letters with the numbers should be fairly easy then.

Comment: +1, although, an easier way could just be to use an array of size 26 and increment the value at index = character - 'a'... at the end of the iteration, you would have the counts.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Pattern Matching like this:

initially..

```
private Matcher matcher; 
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile( pattern ); 
matcher = regexPattern.matcher("");
```

for multiple patterns to match.

```
private final String[] patterns = new String [] {/* instantiate patterns here..*/} 
private Matcher matchers[]; 
for ( int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
Pattern regexPattern = Pattern.compile( pattern[i] ); 
matchers[i] = regexPattern.matcher(""); 

}
```

and then for matching pattern.. you do this..

```
if(matcher.reset(charBuffer).find() ) {//matching pattern.}
```

for multiple matcher check.

```
for ( int i = 0; i < matchers.length; i++ ) if(matchers[i].reset(charBuffer).find() ) {//matching pattern.}
```

Don't use string matching, not efficient.

Always use CharBuffer instead of String.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some C# code (which is reasonably similar to Java):

```
void replace(string s){

    Dictionary<char, int> counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();

    foreach(char c in s){
        // skip spaces
        if(c == ' ') continue;

        // update count for char c
        if(!counts.ContainsKey(c)) counts.Add(c, 1);
        else counts[c]++;
    }

    // replace characters in s
    for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) 
        if(s[i] != ' ') 
            s[i] = counts[s[i]];
}
```

Pay attention to immutable strings in the second loop. Might want to use a `StringBuilder` of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works for lower case strings only.  Horrible horrible code, but I was trying to see how few lines I could write a solution in.

```
public static String letterCount(String in) {
  StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(in.length() * 2);
  int[] count = new int[26];
  for (int t = 1; t >= 0; t--)
    for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
      if (in.charAt(i) != ' ') count[in.charAt(i) - 'a'] += t;
      out.append((in.charAt(i) != ' ') ? "" + count[in.charAt(i) - 'a'] : " ");
    }
  return out.substring(in.length());
}
```